# Missing Operand In GridView Filter C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to Filter GridView Column on Text Change but I am getting Missing Operand After BILL AMOUNT,this is the Column name in GridView.

**Exception**

System.Data.SyntaxErrorException:Syntax Error:Missing Operand After Amount

**Code**

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("BILL AMOUNT = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column name has a white space in it - you need to use brackets:

```
string.Format("[BILL AMOUNT] = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);
```

[This page](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/) explains everything quite nicely

Comment: Thank you so much.